# error 127 while executing makefile.linux

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I wanted to take backup of my MQ objects.

The version of MQ is v6.0.1.0.

OS version is Linux ip-10-0-0-136 2.6.32.19-0.3-ec2 #1 SMP 2010-09-17 20:28:21 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I downloaded MS03 and extracted the files as I wanted to run the command saveqmgr.

When I want to compile makefile.linux I get the following error :

```
/tmp> make -f makefile.linux
gcc -c -DUNIX -Wall -o saveqmgr.o -I. -I/opt/mqm/inc saveqmgr.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [saveqmgr.o] Error 127
```

How do I check what is Error 127? where do I check for errors ?

The linker option set in makefile.linux is

```
LCOPTS = -m64 -o $@ -L$(MQMLIB) -L. $(LIBS)
LCOPTC = -m64 -o $@ -L$(MQMLIB) -L. $(LIBC)

# MQM library directory
MQMLIB = /opt/mqm/lib64
```

Is there anything else I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

See this table of [exit codes with special meaning](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).  `Error 127` corresponds to the preceding `gcc: Command not found`.  You apparently don't have gcc installed on your system, or you don't have it in your `PATH` environment variable.